# Heap size for windows app

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, malloc

I have a Windows7 Maximal 64-bit computer with 8 Gb RAM. I have created a Win32 console aplication in MSVC and wrote as follows:

```
size_t const s_chunkSize = 1024 * 32;
size_t total = 0;
for (;;)
{
    if (!::malloc(s_chunkSize))
    {
        break;
    }
    total += s_chunkSize;
}
printf("total = %li", total);
// yes, I do not free allocated memory for simplicity
```

It output me 2111668224 that is below 2Gb. How can I force my program to allocate more that 2Gb? Do I have to change some MSVC project settings? Or do I have to use not `malloc` but Windows-specific functions? Or do I have to configure Windows somehow?

Comment: Just build the x64 version of the program.  Build + Configuration Manager.  Action solution = New, pick "x64".

Comment: First are you shore your total is valid 64-bit variable? (I have seen some 64-bit variables without 64-bit arithmetics before try to print number of chunks not total memory size). Second 32-bit apps on 64-bit OS runs on emulator (WOW) so the limit should be theoretically 4GB (~3GB).

Comment: @Spektre: only if they are compiled with the "large address aware" linker flag, which is opt-in. Otherwise, the limit is still 2 GB for compatibility reasons.

Comment: Your print statement will print only the lower 32 bits of `total`. Should be `%Iu`.

Comment: @Matteo Italia tahnks for info ... I am not MSVC++ user ... prefer Borland/Embarcadero IDE/Compilers

Comment: @Spektre: there should be an equivalent option in any toolchain; still, it's just a flag in the PE header, so it can be easily changed even after linking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the comments, you must use the /LARGEADDRESSAWARE linker flag to enable the use of >2GB of virtual address space on machines that provide it (typically, 32 bit machines with the /3GB flag or 64 bit machines).  Notice that doing this requires you to exercise extra care when dealing with pointers ( http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/08/12/213468.aspx and articles linked from there), and won't allow you to access more than 4 GB of virtual address space anyway.

A better solution is to build a 64 bit version of your program: you are no longer restricted to a 32 bit address space, and you avoid the caveats of addresses with the high bit set. Obviously, the downside (beside the porting problems that may arise) is that the generated executable will run only on 64 bit  machines.